# What are the configurations needed for enabling the distributed tracing with spring boot 3?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-micrometer, distributed-training

I added following dependencies

- micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave

Added configuration in application.properties

management.tracing.sampling.probability=1.0

logging.pattern.level=%5p [${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}]

But trace and span id’s are coming blank

I am expecting log message to populate values for trace id and span id but it’s blank

Comment: Resolved the issue by following https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33372. These settings are working if we don't have webflux dependency

Comment: If you have WebFlux dependency, but your endpoints are not returning Mono or Flux, adding **Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation();** in the spring boot application class will enable TraceId and SpanId. This solution is not working for endpoints that return Mono/Flux. Did anyone go through this situation?

`public static void main(String[] args) {
 Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation();
 SpringApplication.run(SpringBoot3Application.class, args);
}`

Comment: Above is referred from Reference: https://micrometer.io/docs/observation#instrumentation_of_reactive_libraries